# JSSOR - $Loop option doesn't seem to work

Tags: jssor

I am trying to use JSSOR slider to build a slider.  I want the slides to play through one time, and then stop.

Reading the API documentation, I should be able to do this:

```
var options = {
$AutoPlay: true,
$Loop: 0,
$DragOrientation: 3
};
var jssor_slider = new $JssorSlider$("slider", options);
```

This doesn't work... it plays through, then scrolls back to the beginning and starts again.  I've tried $Loop: false, $Loop: 1, $Loop: 2, and have no change in how it plays through... the idea is that when it stops, I would like to then have a handler for the $EVT_SLIDESHOW_END event that will load a new set of images and start the slideshow again, however, this event is never triggering because the slideshow is not stopping.  Any help with this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the $Loop option controls the behavior of carousel. If value of $Loop is 0, when drag or click next button, it won't go forward.

for your approach, please capture $JssorSlider$.$EVT_STATE_CHANGE event.

```
//Each slide will go through progress of progressBegin, idleBegin, idleEnd, progressEnd. Capture playing state change event then
jssor_slider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_STATE_CHANGE, function(slideIndex, progress, progressBegin, idleBegin, idleEnd, progressEnd)
{
    if(slideIndex == [last slide] && progress == progressEnd)
    {
        //do something when last slide plays over
    }
});
```